# How can i manipulate a javaScript object

Tags: javascript, object, key, qubit

From the below command: __qubit.deliver.cookie.v1.get('_qb_se')

I retrieve something like:

```
{
  610333: {
            e:106949
            t:1533657574344
          },
   686672: {
            e:118370
            t:1533657574344
           },
   704213: {
            e:121077
            t:1533657574344
           },
   738557: {
            e:126419
            t:1533657574344
           }, 
   755358: {
            e:128988
            t:1533657574344
           }, 
   780710: {
            e:132748
            t:1533657574344
           }
    }
```

I want to be able to access the key (eg 610333) and also the e (eg 106949).

How can each value in different variables?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
var object = __qubit.deliver.cookie.v1.get('_qb_se')
var x = object["610333"] // { e: 106949, t: 1533657574344 }
var e = object["106949"].e // 106949
```

See [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: @Maf if you want all the keys use `Object.keys(object)` this will return an array of keys which you can then incorporate into the above example.